# use exec -a to name process but run it in the background immune to CTRL-C

Tags: bash, kill, signals, exec

I would like to start a background process from bash script, but at the same time give it another name and also make it immune to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. I tried the following:

```
exec -a NiceName java -cp ....long java command line &
tail -f logs/the.log
```

I want the `exec` to provide the process another name than just `java`.
I want to start it in the background to be able to immediately run tail on the logs of the process to verify the startup.

This works until I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the script/tail because the SIGINT is passed to the `java` process which terminates too.

I also tried combinations of `(exec ...&)`  and `(exec ...)&`. What does work is

```
exec bash -c "java command line escaping hell&"
tail -f logs/the.log
```

but I would hope there is way without escaping hell. I also tried things with `disown` to no avail.

If I remove the `exec`, the sub-process is immune to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, but then I cannot give it a name.

Comment: start it with `at`.

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimenting I found the way to do this:

```
(trap "" SIGINT; exec -a NiceName java -cp ....long java command line &)
tail -f logs/the.log
```

Ignoring the `SIGINT` in the subshell is inherited by the `exec`ed `java` command. The foreground running `bash`/`tail` can still be terminated with CTRL-C.